# custom Serialize Class to JSon - for really small data

Tags: c#, json, serialization

well,
i have a really simple class:

```
        public class Channel : IContent
        {
            public Guid Guid { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Alias { get; set; }
            public void Set()
            {
               // SAVE JSON DATA
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(string.Join("", this.Guid, ".jsv")))
                {
                    writer.Write("{ \"Title\":", this.Title, "}");
                }
            }
        }
```

Serializing i could do as shown in code,
but how can i load that back into the class? that is the actual question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> please dont refer me to JavaScriptSerializer or DataContracts etc...
>   again, this should be so simple... that i dont think i need all those.

[Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/). No, seriously you need a JSON serializer. Just pick one that you like. The 3 that have been listed work great. And make sure you read [this article](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp) to better understand why you need a JSON serializer.

Comment: i up voted you myself. but it still seems to me that i dont need something that big.

Comment: @Dementic, big? It's built into the framework. In the BCL. Why care about *bigness*? Also you probably might ask yourself: why is it big? Because the problem you are trying to solve is difficult and don't do the mistake of Step 1 on the article I linked to.